# How to add, subtract, etc. two structs element-by-element when they have the same fields

Tags: matlab, class, oop, struct

I have various structs with fields W, P, E, which contain numerical values. I want to develop a clean way to add and subtract these structs without unpacking and repacking in subfunctions each time (which has been my solution thus far)

For example, given:

```
S.W = 2
S.P = 3
S.E = 4

M.W = 20
M.P = 30
M.E = 40
```

I want to be able to do `X = S + M` and end up with:

```
X.W = 22
X.P = 33
X.E = 44
```

My current attempt to do this, is by means of a new class, which looks as follows:

```
classdef CV
    properties
        W
        P
        E
    end
    methods
        function r = plus(o1,o2)
            r = CV;
            r.E = o1.E + o2.E;
            r.P = o1.P + o2.P;
            r.W = o1.W + o2.W;
        end
    end
end
```

This allows for doing S + M and returns a new variable in the same form as the inputs. I'm generally unfamiliar with classes, and wanted to know if this is proper form. If so, I might go ahead and add functions for `minus` and `times` in the `methods` section. However, this seems like it requires a lot of repetitive code and I feel there must be a simpler solution. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You may convert struct into array by `struct2array`, do the computation, and assign the result into the struct based on the dimension of each field of the struct

Comment: That's a good plan but I worry about not having a way to check that all structs have the same order (i.e. since they are all defined in different places in the code, I don't want to worry that they all were defined in the order W, P, E If that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code directly works on structs without nesting them in a class.  It is assumed that the two input structs have the same field names (in this example W, P, and E), however, the order of those may be arbitrary (you mentioned in a comment that this is important for your application).

```
function X = structplus(S, M)
fn = fieldnames(S);
for i = 1 : numel(fn)
  X.(fn{i}) = M.(fn{i}) + S.(fn{i});
end
end
```

So defining

```
S.W = 2
S.P = 3
S.E = 4

M.E = 40
M.P = 30
M.W = 20
```

(note the reverse order of M) and calling

```
X = structplus(S, M)
```

yields a struct with field names that are ordered like the first argument:

```
X = 
  struct with fields:
    W: 22
    P: 33
    E: 44
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice elegant solution. Do you know of a way to do it without looping as well? I find if I use cellfun rather than the loop, I can't get a struct output

Comment: @teepee So, `cell2struct(cellfun(@(n) M.(n)+S.(n), fn, 'UniformOutput', false), fn, 1)` ? But `cellfun` is more or less the same as a `for` loop

Comment: `cellfun` is *slower* than the explicit loop in pretty much every nontrivial case

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Le Phlaux's answer, you can provide a function handle to the required binary operator (e.g. `@plus`, `@minus`) and work on sub-structures recursively

```
function out = structBinaryFunc(in1, in2, func)
fn = fieldnames(in1);
for ii = 1:numel(fn)
    if isstruct(in1.(fn{ii}))
        out.(fn{ii}) = structBinaryFunc(in1.(fn{ii}), in2.(fn{ii}), func)
    else
        out.(fn{ii}) = func(in1.(fn{ii}), in2.(fn{ii}));
    end
end
```

For your example you would call `X = structBinaryFunc(S, M, @plus);`.